# Using Android constraint layout with bazel build

Tags: android, bazel, android-constraintlayout

Using `bazel` version `0.4.5-homebrew`, it is possible to reference e.g. the `appcompat-v7` support library by using `"@androidsdk//com.android.support:appcompat-v7-25.3.1"` as a dependency. However, using the intuitive `"@androidsdk//com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-1.0.1"` to pull in the constraint layout support library results in:

> no such package '@androidsdk//com.android.support.constraint': BUILD file not found on package path

`bazel query @androidsdk//... | grep constraint` has no results. Using the same local Android SDK, I am able to reference the constrant layout library in Gradle projects.

Any ideas/workarounds? I did submit [an issue on Bazel's github](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2830), so maybe I'll get an answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can read on the now [closed GitHub issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2830).

This was an issue with Bazel itself. Workaround are available (see issue) and the issue been fixed in the Bazel codebase.